# mayavi - setting the [x,y,z] extent of an image programatically

Tags: python, image, 3d, transformation, mayavi

I have some data that consists of several 2D images that I would like to render in specific [x,y,z] positions relative to one another using `mayavi2 (v4.3.0)`.

[From the documentation](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.imshow) it seems that I should just be able to do this with `mlab.imshow()`. Unfortunately, mayavi throws an exception when I call `imshow` specifying the `extent` parameter (`AttributeError: 'ImageActor' object has no attribute 'actor'`).

I also tried setting the x,y and z data directly by modifying `im.mlab_source.x,y,z...`. Weirdly, whilst this correctly changes the x and y extents, it does nothing to the z-position even though `im.mlab_source.z` clearly changes.

Here's a runnable example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import lena
from mayavi import mlab

def normal_imshow(img=lena()):
    return mlab.imshow(img,colormap='gray') 

def set_extent(img=lena()):
    return mlab.imshow(img,extent=[0,100,0,100,50,50],colormap='cool')

def set_xyz(img=lena()):
    im = mlab.imshow(img,colormap='hot')    
    src = im.mlab_source
    print 'Old z :',src.z
    src.x = 100*(src.x - src.x.min())/(src.x.max() - src.x.min())
    src.y = 100*(src.y - src.y.min())/(src.x.max() - src.y.min())
    src.z[:] = 50
    print 'New z :',src.z
    return im

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # this works
    normal_imshow()

    # # this fails (AttributeError)
    # set_extent()

    # weirdly, this seems to work for the x and y axes, but does not change
    # the z-postion even though data.z does change
    set_xyz()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that this is a [known bug](https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/pull/45) in mayavi. However, it is possible to change the orientation, position and scale of an `ImageActor` object after it has been created:

```
obj = mlab.imshow(img)
obj.actor.orientation = [0, 0, 0]  # the required orientation 
obj.actor.position = [0, 0, 0]     # the required  position 
obj.actor.scale = [0, 0, 0]        # the required scale
```