# Is it possible to directly apply an affine transformation matrix to a Mayavi ImageActor object?

Tags: python, transformation, mayavi

I'm using **Mayavi** to render some imaging data that consists of multiple 2D planes within a 3D volume, the position, orientation, and scale of which are defined by 4x4 rigid body affine transformation matrices. Each plane consists of:

- An array of 2D image data, which I display using `mayavi.mlab.imshow`
- A set of ROIs consisting of lines and points that I draw using `mayavi.mlab.points3d` and `mayavi.mlab.plot3d` respectively.

I transform my points and line vertices from a 2D reference plane into the 3D space by dotting their coordinates with my affine matrix. Based on my previous question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845338/mayavi-setting-the-x-y-z-extent-of-an-image-programatically), I figured out that I could set the positions and orientations of the `ImageActor` objects individually, using:

```
obj = mlab.imshow(img)
obj.actor.orientation = [pitch, roll, yaw] # the required orientation (deg)
obj.actor.position = [dx, dy, dz] # the required position 
obj.actor.scale = [sx, sy, sz] # the required scale
```

Now the plot looks like this:

[image]

Everything lines up nicely, but it's very difficult to interpret because the planes are so densely spaced in z. What I'd now like to be able to do is 'stretch out' the z-axis by some scaling factor. In the case of the points and lines, this is very easy to do - all I do is multiply all of the transformed z-coordinates by a scaling factor.

However, I can't figure out how to apply the same transformation to the images. If I just scale the z-position, the rotation and scaling of the images will of course be wrong, and my plotted points/lines will no longer fall on the same plane as the image:

[image]

What I need to do is apply a non-rigid affine transformation that incorporates shear as well as rotation, translation, and scaling to my images.

Is there any way I can manually apply shear to an `ImageActor`, or even better just directly apply an arbitrary 4x4 affine matrix that I've precomputed?

Comment: I don't think that would work for me. It sounds pretty horrendous, but I could imagine perhaps setting up a projection matrix that would make one image appear as though it had been suitably affine-transformed. However I have several images that I need to render in a single scene, each of which needs a different transformation applied to it.

Answer (score 2):

`ImageActor`, which ultimately is a wrapper for `tvtk.ImageActor`, has a `user_matrix` property, which lets you assign a 4D transformation matrix.

Starting with a random image,

```py
    import numpy as np
    from mayavi.mlab import imshow
    s = np.random.random((10, 10))
    image = imshow(s, colormap='gist_earth', interpolate=False)
```

gives us the following ...

[image: Random image]

Creating a transformation matrix and setting a term to give it some shear ...

```py
    from tvtk.api import tvtk
    transform_matrix = tvtk.Matrix4x4()
    transform_matrix.set_element(0, 1, 2.5)
    image.actor.user_matrix = transform_matrix
```

gives us ...

[image: Random image with shear]

`set_element` has the signature `(row, col, value)`, so you should be able to set elements on that matrix as needed.